# How to modify spatial extent of a landscape

Tags: netlogo

I created a landscape that it is possible to modify at each simulation by changing paramaters in the interface.

For my simulated landscapes, I considered that `one patch = 100 m²`. For the moment, the spatial extent of my landscape is `0.3 km² (51 patches x 51 patches x 100)` if I didn't make a mistake.

Ideally, I would like to have a spatial extent of `10 000 km²`. I made some tests and obtained an internal error when I specified `max-pxcor = 1000`, `max-pycor = 1000` and `patch size = 1 pixel` in model settings. So, is it possible to have a landscape with a spatial extent of `10 000 km²`?

Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would of course be to just increase the patches to 1km². Then you only need the view to be `100x100`. If you have agents on the landscape, you could then just divide their sizes by 10 and speeds by 100 (since each patch is 100 times wider and taller than before).

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I don’t think that I can increase patches to 1 km² because to build the least-cost path and to assign a cost at each patch, one patch has to correspond to one land cover type. In a real landscape of my study area, one white corridor (see figure above) = 100m. So, if one patch = 1 km², I can’t assign an unique cost to white corridors.

Comment: Ah that's too bad. Just so I'm clear, each white patch must be 100m² or 100m wide?

Comment: Sorry Bryan, I make a mistake. In a real landscape of my study area, corridor width = 10m. So, I considered that all patches in Netlogo = 10m x 10m = 100m². I hope that it's clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that I need 100 000 000 patches of 100m² to have 10 000 km² i.e. 10 000 x 10 000 patches.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you might be using up your computer's memory. First, make sure in the "Settings" on the Interface that you set the Location of Origin to "Corner"; otherwise, if you leave the origin at the center then your space will really be 2000 x 2000. Then set max-pxcor and max-pycor to 999 (so space goes 0 to 999).

It works on my computer...

Comment: See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#howbig for advice on increasing the JVM's heap ceiling, which limits the number of agents. (Switching to a 64-bit JVM may be needed if you need a really huge heap.)

Comment: Thanks Steve and Seth. I set the location of Origin to "Corner", max-pxcor and max-pycor to 999 and I obtain a spatial extent of 1000 patches x 1000 patches (i.e. 100 km²) without an error message. Even if it’s not possible to have a spatial extent of 10 000 km², I would be happy to have at least 1000 km². From the link, I tried to modify -Xmx1024m by -Xmx2048m in "NetLogo 5.0.5.vmoptions" file of the NetLogo folder, but I obtain the message: “access is denied”. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I modified the "NetLogo 5.0.5.vmoptions" file by testing with -Xmx1024m, -Xmx1280m, -Xmx1536m, -Xmx1792m, -Xmx2048m and Netlogo doesn't work from -Xmx1536m (I used computers with 8GB and 32GB of RAM). Is Netlogo only limited to 1GB of RAM with 64-bit system ?

Answer (score 0):

In case amount of pixels in the view (count patches * patch-size ^ 2) is the cause of error instead of amount of patches:
running "set-patch-size 1 resize-world 0 999 0 999"
instead of
"resize-world 0 999 0 999 set-patch-size 1"
should remove errors caused by too many pixels in view.

10000x10000 world? For me testing a world with 1 patch and patch size larger than 9000 pixels starts causing errors. A list with a size of 10000 * 10000 elements takes too much memory.

Displaying a world of such size is possible in netlogo. Contents of the world would have to be scattered around in files on the harddrive instead of memory. Visualization can be done with bitmap extension or drawing/stamping with a turtle. Partially visualizing the world using patches is also possible.